# Understanding a mapping to a disc

Tags: algebraic-topology, homological-algebra, homotopy-theory

I was self-studying some fundamental algebraic topology from Elements of Topology by T.B. Singh.

I came across an example which says that if $f$ is identity map on $\Bbb{D}^2$ and $g$ : $\Bbb{D}^2$ $\rightarrow$ $\Bbb{D}^2$ by $g(z) = -z$.

Then $H : \Bbb{D}^2\times I \rightarrow \Bbb{D}^2$
defined by $H(z,t)$ = z$e^{\pi i t}$

is a homotopy from $f$ to $g$ relative to origin.

What I couldn't understand is that why is it defined..as in why is z$e^{\pi i t}$ is in $\Bbb{D}^2$ if $z$ is in $\Bbb{D}^2$ and $t$ is in $[0,1]$.

I can see that for such $t$, $e^{\pi i t}$ will be a unit circle but I can't visualise its multiplication with $z$ to be in $\Bbb{D}^2$.

Then I am also unable to show that $H$ is continuous.

Next, how to show that g is continuous?

If I let $U$ to be open in $\Bbb{D}^2$. Then $g^{-1}(U)$ = {$x \in \Bbb{D}^2$: $-x \in U$}. I can't deduce anything from here

Help, please!

Comment: What is the length of $ze^{\pi i t}$?

Comment: Is it an arc?.. I can't understand what will we be even getting on multiplying points on circle with points on sphere

Answer (score 1):

$\mathbb{D}^2$ is just the set $\lbrace z \in \mathbb{C} \text{ } | \text{ } |z| \leq 1\rbrace$.

So if $z \in \mathbb{D}^2$, then for any $t \in [0,1]$, $ze^{i\pi t} \in \mathbb{D}^2$.

Moreover $ze^{i\pi \times 0} = z$ and $ze^{i\pi \times 1} = -z$

The continuity of $H$ just comes from the continuity of exponential map and multiplication in $\mathbb{C}$.

Comment: Is ||$z_1z_2$|| = ||$z_1$|| ||$z_2$||?

Comment: With the complex modulus ? Of course !

Comment: Oh yes yes right

Comment: Is it some result that if h: X $\times$ Y $\rightarrow$ Z defined as h(x,y) = f(x)g(y) and if f and g are continuous then h is also continuous?

Comment: Yes ! Try to prove it if you are not convinced :)

Comment: I know that composition of two continuous functions is continuous and projection maps are continuous. Should I use that to prove?

Comment: Not really. Here, you have to prove that the product on two continuous functions is continuous. I am sure you know that, but trying to re-prove it can be a good exercise.

Answer (score -1):

Hint: Multiplication by $e^{i\theta}$ is counter-clockwise rotation by angle $\theta$.